# SpriteKit images out of focus

Tags: image, sprite-kit, resolution, blurry

As the title says I have a little problem with my images.
I provide to the application @2x and @3x images with the correct resolutions/sizes but some of them look slightly blurred.

I mean, is not a problematic aspect because they are just a little out of focus but I really want to figure it out what causes this.

Looking for an answer I ran into an user says that the problem is about "center property". Could someone explain to me what this stands for? The images's scale is 100%, I'm not trying to stretch them...

Comment: Are you able to provide screen shots of what is happening? or are you stretching the scene or parent node at all? What is the size of your scene?

Comment: @SkylerLauren I think I solved the problem. I was "playing" with photoshop and my images and I figure it out that if just one value of the image size is **odd** (for instance: 219 x 220) the image will be blurred while if both values are even (220 x 200) the image will be correctly showed! Maybe this could be the result of the 2x retina display I think. But what about the 3x resolution? Do those values have to be divisible per 3?

Comment: Odd numbers can cause some issues from time to time. If you think in points it helps. Assume it is 219 @2x in pixels but it has issues trying to figure it out in points is it 110 or 109 in points? So it does its best and you might not end up with crips images. You have to think in points (1x) and work up from there if you want 200 you need 400 and 600 respectively so points can be calculated correctly. If that makes sense. Glad you figured it out and best of luck :)